# Casting exception transforming Lists to Arrays

Tags: java, string, casting, arraylist

I would like to build an array of arrays starting from a list, but I get a casting exception. Anybody knows why? Here is the code

```
List<String[]> listofarray=new ArrayList<String[]>();
//...filling the list...
String[][] ob= (String[][]) listofarray.toArray();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`List#toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) method without any argument returns an `Object[]`. You need to use the overloaded generic version - [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) passing `String[][]` as argument. Then you wouldn't need to cast the result back.

```
String[][] ob= listofarray.toArray(new String[listofarray.size()][]);
```

Comment: There's no need to add the `(String[][])` cast.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oops. Removed it. Thanks :)